# Poner una subtabla en una tabla HTML - JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatables

En la vista de caja estan todas las ventas realizadas en la parte de detalle hay un click que tiene que desplegarse para que muestre su detalle, no se si me dejo entender.
Hasta el momento ya e creado la subtabla pero aun no lo puedo colocar en la cuando le de click en el icono del **+**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**MI codigo HTML de la tabla:**

```
<div class="box-body">
<table id="tabla_ventas"
class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover responsive"
cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead class="background-thead">
<tr>
<th>Nº</th>
<th>CLIENTE</th>
<th>TOTAL</th>
<th style="width: 200px;">FEHA</th>
<th>DETALLE</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**JQuery de la tabla**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {

        tabla_ventas = $('#tabla_ventas').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "order": [],

            "ajax": {
                "url": baseurl + 'Caja/listar_ventas',
                "type": "POST",
                "data": {"ci_csrf_token": ciCsrfToken}
            },

            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3],
                    "orderable": false
                }
            ],
            "language": {
                "processing": "Procesando...",
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "emptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "infoPostFix": "",
                "search": "Buscar:",
                "url": "",
                "infoThousands": ",",
                "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "paginate": {
                    "first": "Primero",
                    "last": "Último",
                    "next": "Siguiente",
                    "previous": "Anterior"
                },
                "aria": {
                    "sortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                    "sortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                }
            },
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 15, 20, 25], [10, 15, 20, 25]],
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
        }); 
    });
});
```

**El codigo JQuery**

function detalle_venta(codigo) {

```
//    alert(codigo);
    var tr = $('#myTable tbody').closest('tr');
    var row = tabla_ventas.row(tr);
    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + 'Caja/traer_detalle',
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: {codigo: codigo},
        success: function (result) {
            if (row.child.isShown()) {

                row.child.hide(result);
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            } else {

                row.child(result).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

**El codigo de Controlador Llenar tabla**

```
public function listar_ventas() {
        $pagos = $this->caja->obtener_data_pagos();
        /* $this->asistencia->obtener_todos(); */
        $estado = null;
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST ['start'];
        foreach ($pagos as $pago) {
            $no ++;
            $row = array();
            $row [] = '<div class="text-left">' . 'VEN000' . $pago->id_venta . '</div>';
            $row [] = $pago->nombres_completos;
            $row [] = $pago->total;
            $row [] = $pago->fecha_venta;
            $row [] = '<div onclick="detalle_venta(' . $pago->id_venta . ')" class="text-center"><a><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i></a></div>';
            $data [] = $row;
        }
        $output = array(
            "draw" => $_POST ['draw'],
            "recordsTotal" => $this->caja->contador_total_pagos(),
            "recordsFiltered" => $this->caja->contador_filtrado_pagos(),
            "data" => $data
        );
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

**El codigo de Controlador traer_detalle**

```
public function traer_detalle() {
        $buscar = $this->input->post('codigo');
        $reg = $this->caja->traer_detalle($buscar);

        if (COUNT($reg) != 0) {//VALIDACION
            echo "            <table class='table table-hover  table-condensed table-bordered' >";
            echo "            <thead style='color:white;background:#4FC3F7;'>";
            echo "            <tr>";
            echo "            <th class='alnright' width=10% style='background:#FFF; border: hidden; border-right: 1px solid black;'></th>";
            echo "            <th class='text-center' width=5% style=' color: #000; border: 1px solid black;'><b>N°</b></th>";
            echo "            <th class='text-center' width=20% style=' color: #000; border: 1px solid black;' ><b>PRODUCTO</b></th>";
            echo "            <th class='text-center' width=10% style=' color: #000; border: 1px solid black;' ><b>CANTIDAD </b></th>";
            echo "            <th class='text-center' width=10% style=' color: #000; border: 1px solid black;' ><b>PRECIO CAMBIO</b></th>";
            echo "            <th class='text-center' width=10% style=' color: #000; border: 1px solid black;' ><b>SUBTOTAL</b></th>";
            echo "            </tr>";
            echo "            </thead>";
            echo "            <tbody>";

            $contador = 0;

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($reg); $i++) {
                $contador ++;
                $accesorio = $reg[$i]['nombre'];
                $PRECIO = $reg[$i]['precio'];
                $CANTIDAD = $reg[$i]['cantidad'];
                $SUBTOTAL = $reg[$i]['subtotal'];

                echo "            <tr>";
                echo "            <td style='border: hidden; border-right: 1px solid black;' width='5px'>&nbsp;</td>";
                echo "            <td class='text-center' style='color:white;background:#ECEFF1;; color: #000; border: 1px solid black;'><b>$contador</b></td>";
                echo "            <td class='text-center' style='color:white;background:#ECEFF1; color: #000; border: 1px solid black;'><b>$accesorio</b></td>";
                echo "            <td class='text-center' style='color:white;background:#ECEFF1; color: #000; border: 1px solid black;'><b>$PRECIO</b></td>";
                echo "            <td class='text-center' style='color:white;background:#ECEFF1; color: #000; border: 1px solid black;'><b>$CANTIDAD</b></td>";
                echo "            <td class='text-center' style='color:white;background:#ECEFF1; color: #000; border: 1px solid black;'><b>$SUBTOTAL</b></td>";
                echo "            </tr>";
            }

            echo "            </tbody>";
            echo "            </table>";
        }
    }
```

**El codigo del Modelo**

```
public function traer_detalle($buscar) {
        $this->db_caja->reconnect();
        $query = $this->db_caja->query("SELECT pro.nombre,detalle_venta.* FROM detalle_venta 
                                       INNER JOIN producto pro on pro.id_producto=detalle_venta.id_producto WHERE id_venta='$buscar'");
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: En la misma pagina de DataTable esta el ejemplo que necesitas: https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: Ivan More Flores, pudiste encontrar la solución de poder ver los detalles?